# Docker Image layers and ENTRYPOINT sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, environment-variables

I have the following dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.3.3-jdk-8

#install node
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -qq update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm

# TODO could uninstall some build dependencies
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10

# Install packages for envsubst
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y --force-yes && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*;
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gettext-base


# Create app directory 
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# cache package.json and node_modules to speed up builds
ADD src src
ADD package.json package.json
ADD node_modules node_modules
ADD pom.xml pom.xml
ADD Gruntfile.js Gruntfile.js
Add gulpfile.js gulpfile.js
ADD settings.xml settings.xml

# Substitute dependencies from environment variables
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 8000
```

Here is the entrypoint script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

envsubst < "/usr/src/app/src/js/envapp.js" > "/usr/src/app/src/js/app.js"
mvn clean  install -DskipTests -s settings.xml 
npm start
```

Note that the line  `envsubst < "/usr/src/app/src/js/envapp.js" > "/usr/src/app/src/js/app.js"` reads the environment and updates the app.js file

I have confirmed that the file is updated by sshing into the container and opening the file
However when I open the app in the browser it appears that it is still reading the old value of the app.js file.

After a lot of debugging I feel that haveing the `npm start` command still reads an old layer in the docker file. Is there a way that the new changes are picked up in the `npm start  line?

I also tried having npm start as an argument to ENTRYPOINT but still have the same effect. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

I also tried forking the image so I copy the files in one image and use this as a base image for the image that does the environment manipultion
But still have the same problem

Here is how I run the docker container

```
docker run -e "ENVVARIABLE=VALUE" -i <image-name>
```

Comment: Maybe you should build again with no cache `docker build --no-cache .`

Comment: Trying it out now, does the --no-cache flag not commit layers? The doc says  'don use cache  not sure if the cache  is old layers of the same image>?

Comment: I still have the same issue after building it with no-cache flag

Comment: Change the last line of entrypoint script to `exec npm start`.

Comment: @user_mda `--no-cache` will tell docker to re-run a build step from scratch even if it believes it already has the result in its cache. It's a way to ensure caching isn't breaking the build somehow and docker isn't smart enough to understand that.

Comment: running the build now, does having the 'npm start' command as a CMD instruction pick up the layer thats aded in the COPY src src step?

Comment: Changing it to exec npm start also does not fix it and it still reads data from old layer generated by the COPY instruction

Comment: You've posted the Dockerfile and the entrypoint script, but can you share how you run this? docker command line, or docker-compose.yml, or whatever you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132723/discussion-between-user-mda-and-dan-lowe).

Comment: Hi Dan, I've postedthe run command, nothing fancy just setting an env variable at runtime